# Can a user's input be used to add an object to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I know you can use a user's input and put a String or int into an array but is it possible to put in objects that were created from other methods or is the only way to input an array with user input through primitive data types and String?

EDIT: Do we have to use the toString() method?

Comment: Answer is yes. What do you try something.

Comment: You can store anything inside an array, not only primitives

Comment: Computers were used to put a man on the moon (at least according to some people), so you're going to have to reach pretty far to come up with something that *can't* be done.

Comment: I'm an amateur when it comes to Java (or programming in general) so I'm still learning all the methods and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A User can only input primitive data types. but this input can be used as parameters to call any kind of method to create an object as you like and this object can be stored in an array of objects.

Comment: Ah creating an object. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a user's input be used to add an object to an array?

Yes, of course. Take a look at the example below.

```
class Student
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

//In the main
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
Student[] students = new Student[10];

for(int x=0; x<students.length; x++){
    String name = scn.nextLine();
    int age = scn.nextInt();
    students[x] = new Student(name, age);
}
```

You can have an array of any type (including primitives and objects). Objects itself can hold fields which can be input from the user, thus what you want to do is possible.